# Google Geocoding API, free?

Tags: google-api, licensing, google-geocoding-api

I found the the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) service which is very useful.
but in all sample appears necessary to put an argument called `Key` for provide the google `Api Key`. That implies that it involves costs, but I saw that it works well without this argoment.
example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA
```

You can count on? they have any limitations?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: Have you tried reading Google's documentation on the API? It will explain how to get an API key.

Comment: Just google for 'Google Geocoding API license'

Comment: Latest Update: We need an API key appended in every request else it won't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits)**

The Google Geocoding API has the following limits in place:

Users of the free API:

- 2,500 requests per 24 hour period.
- 5 requests per second.

Google Maps API for Work customers:

- 100,000 requests per 24 hour period.
- 10 requests per second.

Comment: Must a google map be used along with it ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @abraham I have only requested 2 times and it says "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API". what do you mean by 2500 requests?

Comment: @LorenceHernandez , google terms have changed since july 2018. Now free requests are limited to 1 and you'll have to move to a pay-as-you-go plan. See : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing?hl=fr#pricing-for-the-geocoding-api

Comment: And in 2021 it seems there are no free requests at all, now it's $5 per 1k of requests from the very first request.

Comment: The above information is outdated (as per Aug-2022). Please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57749009/9700298).