# How much request is free with geocoding api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-geocoding-api

I want to get the address from latitude/longitude using Google Geocoding API. For that, I want to know, how many no of hit can be done with a free account?

Bellow link showing the 2,500 requests per 24 hour period free.

[Google Geocoding API, free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925050/google-geocoding-api-free)

Kindly clear me, it is still free hit exist with Google Geocoding API or not.
If no, then how many hits are free with this API?

Comment: Google changed their policy since then. Now you only get 1 free request per day. However, if you set up a billing account with a credit card you get 300$ worth of usage. see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#GCP_paid_account)

Answer (score 7):

Upon setting up your billing account, you will be entitled to have **one time $300 free credit** (Usable for any Google Cloud Platform products) and a **monthly recurring $200 free credit** (Exclusive for Google Maps API only), the Geocoding API is currently priced at 0.005 USD, with that said, you may have the following requests as follows:

300 USD / 0.005 USD = 60,000 requests

200 USD / 0.005 = 40,000 requests

If you haven't used your one time $300 free credit, then you may have 100,000 geocoding requests for the first month, then for the succeeding months, you may have 40,000 geocoding requests that will be covered by the monthly recurring $200 free credit.

You may learn more about the pricing by visiting the [pricing sheet](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#geocoding)

You may also use the [Pricing Calculator](https://mapsplatformtransition.withgoogle.com/calculator) if you'd wish to compute for other SKUs as well, note that this also take your free credit(monthly recurring $200 only) into account.

Answer (score 4):

Google has changed their billing policy a while ago you should consult [Usage and billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing)

> Pay-As-You-Go Pricing
>
> The Geocoding API uses a pay-as-you-go pricing model.
>
> How usage and billing work under the pay-as-you-go model
>
> 1. The Google Maps Platform APIs are billed by SKU.
> 2. Usage is tracked for each Product SKU, and an API may have more than one Product SKU.
> 3. Cost is calculated by: SKU Usage x Price per each use.
> 4. For each billing account, for qualifying Google Maps Platform SKUs, a $200 USD Google 1. Maps Platform credit is available each month, and automatically applied to the qualifying SKUs.
>
> See guide to [understanding billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#billing-overview) for more information.
>
> Pricing for the Geocoding API
>
> Under the pay-as-you-go pricing model, requests for the **Geocoding API are billed using the SKU for Geocoding**.

When you create a new account and connect a credit card to it you will be given $300 credit that you can use to test your application before you bring it live.

Comment: we have no sku, we have to hit with lat/log only.

Answer (score 2):

It is expensive. It costs $5 per 1000 hits up to 100,000 hits. And onwards up to 500,000 hits, it will cost $4 per 1000 hits.
Google gives initial $200 credit but you must have to restrict your APIs. Otherwise, your free credit will be exhausted within a week.

[image: cost chart]

Answer (score 1):

To use Google's Geocoding service you need an account on the [Google Maps Platform](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/). The trial account as well as the Pay-as-you-go priced account which you will be forced to upgrade to after one year both feature ≥ 200 USD/month worth of service.

For both types of account a CreditCard is required.

200 USD worth of service allow for 40'000 Geocoding requests per month (see [pricelist](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/?&sign=0)). Any additional request is billed at 0.005 USD/request.

The service for Geocoding has the [SKU "Geocoding"](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/sku-mapping-old-to-new#places) and is part of the "Geocoding API" which in term is part of the product "Places" of the "Google Maps Platform".

The Geocoding service has a limit of [50 requests per second](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_apis), but there is no (longer a) limit per day.

Comment: Is one request limited to one address or can one request contain a list of addresses to be converted in their lat/long coordinates?

Comment: **One** request performs _reverse geocoding_ or _geocoding_ for **one** location.
This can easily be seen from the documentation and examples:
1) [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding) (use case in original question), e.g. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=47.7510741,-120.7401385&key=YOUR_API_KEY
2) and [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding) (your use case), e.g. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Washington&key=YOUR_API_KEY